# What is wrong with my Rails SMTP config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, smtp

I was given this smtp server address: klee.cdlib.org (behind our firewall and does not need password/login) and my own local address where my dev application is running is http://128.48.204.195:3000

Here are my current configurations in the development.rb file:

```
      config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
      config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "klee.cdlib.org",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => 'klee.cdlib.org',  #'http://128.48.204.195:3000',
#      :user_name            => '',
#      :password             => '',
      :authentication       => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
      config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

This gives an error:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (550 5.7.1 <my@email.com>... Relaying denied
```

I am also not sure about the difference between domain and address fields.  What should be in which? :) And what else am I possibly doing wrong to get this error?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rails setup seems ok. Denied relaying is probably raised because the mail server actually does not allow relaying any mails for mails from 128.48.204.195. It's possible that the mail server configuration is not configured for that or perhaps it's configured to relay mails from klee.cdlib.org which has no reverse DNS entry.

Comment: Agreed. Unless the SMTP server is simply faulting you for an invalid email, it's most likely the SMTP server's policy for spam control to disallow emails from your domain. The simplest solution is to change your SMTP server. (Gmail is a good alternative)

More info: http://www.eudora.com/techsupport/kb/1593hq.html